# Adding single click event to multiple linkbuttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have looked at other post but nothing explained what I want to do very well.

At runtime I have x amount of LinkButtons added to the form by a repeater dependant on the data it retrieves from the database:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="variantRepeat" runat="server" 
    onitemcommand="variantRepeat_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate><li><asp:LinkButton ID="varLink" runat="server" CommandName="Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("variantID") %>'><%# Eval ("variant_name") %></asp:LinkButton></li></ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It is supposed to, when clicked Fire of an event backstage

```
    protected void varLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewCollection views = prodView.Views;
    }
```

Then set up some views. However I need the CommandArgument to go through as that holds the key to look up inside the `prodView.Views` .

It doesn't have to be `variantID` that is passed but could be and Int depending on which one, just need some indication as to what view to display!

I have all the views created at page init and added to the page dynamically at init.

I use the entity framework to query the database through a few views! (found that to be easier to get complex data from relational databases!)

I don't know how to link up all those LinkButtons so that I can programmatically switch views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's more detailed code:

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtVariant" /> 

<asp:Repeater ID="variantRepeat" runat="server" 
    OnItemCommand="variantRepeat_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="varLink" runat="server" CommandName="Click" 
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("variantID") %>'>
                <%# Eval ("variant_name") %></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
[Serializable]
public class Variant
{
    public Variant() { }
    public int variantID { get; set; }
    public string variant_name { get; set; }
}

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public Variant[] Variants
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Variants"] == null)
                return new Variant[] { };
            return (Variant[])ViewState["Variants"];
        }
        set { ViewState["Variants"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Variants = new Variant[] { 
                new Variant() { variantID = 1, variant_name = "T1" },
                new Variant() { variantID = 2, variant_name = "T2" }
            };
            variantRepeat.DataSource = Variants;
            variantRepeat.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void variantRepeat_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Click":
                var variant = Variants.FirstOrDefault(v => v.variantID.ToString() == e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                if (variant != null)
                {
                    txtVariant.Text = variant.variantID.ToString();
                    // show the right view
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is using the ViewState as the storing container, but you can also use Session.

Comment: Please see updated code. It's a working example, but you should get the idea.